# Highlight each query keyword in different color solr

Tags: solr, colors, highlight

I want to highlight each query keyword in solr response with different color.

Example query= 'first and second'.
I want the results to be like:

query results: **first** random text and **second** //response end
The background of 'first' should be color 1 and that of 'second' should be color 2.

I have tried using  `hl.fragmentsBuilder` but was unable to get the results to highlight.

Comment: Waht did you try with hl.fragmentsBuilder? You'll have to configure a fragmentbuilder first, then reference that.

Comment: actually i am new to solr, could you guide me as to how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

in lucene , only FastVectorHighlighter class suport mutil color tag , i don't know how to implements in solr ,but it's can be do this in lucene :

```
  FragmentsBuilder fragmentsBuilder= new ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder(BaseFragmentsBuilder.COLORED_PRE_TAGS,BaseFragmentsBuilder.COLORED_POST_TAGS);  

  FastVectorHighlighter fastHighlighter2=new FastVectorHighlighter(true, true, fragListBuilder, fragmentsBuilder);
```

maybe this is useful for you !

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need to do it using solr.

Comment: It seems that there is the [same thing in Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragmentsBuilder) !

Comment: Can you me how to use it? I already wrote in the description that I tried using this and was unable to make it work

Comment: Can you guide me how to use it? I already wrote in the description that I tried using this and was unable to make it work

Comment: Did you get any solutions?